# jquery submit does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with submit form. After click on button alert box does not appear. It looks like `event.preventDefault()` prevents submitting. But I need that preventDefault to prevent reloading page after jQuery load. 
Any ideas how to fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    new_submit();

    initOnClickMainMenu();//there is problem

});

function initOnClickMainMenu(){

    $("#menu_register").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        addToContent("#main_content","register.html",function(){
            hideShowAlertBox("#register_alert","hide","");
        });
    this.blur();
    });

    $("#menu_login").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        addToContent("#main_content","login.html",function(){
            hideShowAlertBox("#login_alert","hide","");
        });
        this.blur(); 
    });
}

function addToContent(content,htmlFile,callback){
    //need to prevent realoading page
    $(content).load(htmlFile,callback);
}

function new_submit(){
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        alert("DONE");
    });
}
```

menu part in index.html

```
<div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a id="menu_register" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span> Register</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a id="menu_login" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
</div>
```

and login.html form (register is same)

```
<form class="form-field" action="" role="form" method="post" name="login">
<div id="login_alert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Nickname:</label>
<input name="nickname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your nickname">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Password:</label>
<input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Your password">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

**FIX**
After googling I find that loaded DOM does not have event listeners so I added it after load and it now works.

```
addToContent("#main_content","register.html",function(event){
            hideShowAlertBox("#register_alert","hide","");
            new_submit();
        });
```

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` in the `submit()` handler.

Comment: You need to `return false;` on `function new_submit(){}` otherwise, the page will continue to try and submit the data

Comment: check my answer. if you meant submit button not #menu_register / #menu_register button.

Comment: check my answer, i m sure this will work

Comment: @dsv_dsv, check my answer for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two way to do this. Either add `return false;` to stop redirect issue or add it on form 'submit' event.

**Return false Example**

```
function new_submit(){
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        alert("DONE");
        return false;
    });
}
```

**form 'submit' event.**

```
function new_submit(){
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    alert('You submitted the form!');
  });
}
```

Comment: there is no redirect issue i believe. this is some thing listener is not working when dynamic content get updated. Return false will not work !

Comment: "But I need that preventDefault to prevent reloading page after jQuery load. Any ideas how to fix it." here is the text of his first paragraph. did you read this @Venkatraman

Comment: .load will not reload page , but form submit event reload page.

Comment: i believe reload is not only the problem bhavin. also dynamic content loosing the event listener

Comment: may be let it decide to the question owner. what exactly issue sis

Comment: @Venkatraman is right I mean jquaery load function. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `new_submit` Method with jQuery `on` method instead of jquery `submit` method.

```
function new_submit(){
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    alert('You submitted the form!');
  });
}
```

Comment: Still not work, problem is not in submit function it works if I not click on `#menu_register` or `#menu_login` button.

Comment: Check the updated answer to update this variable context inside listeners

Comment: Hope you included the jquery in the head tag and these jquery code just before the body tag. because its working fine. check the demo in the answer

Comment: If I add form to index.html and press submit it works but after click on menu items in fuction `initOnClickMainMenu()` and then press submit button on loaded file it does not work

Comment: Ok use on listener is a issue !

Comment: Updated the new_submit method. check the answer.

Comment: Can I suggest that instead of just having a complete copy of the code (which I do understand is required for the snippet) you actually explain (at the top of the answer) exactly what it is you've fixed.  Otherwise people have to read line-by-line through the entire answer to find the potentially tiny change(s) you've made